# How can I create A template from sql query by using C# and regex?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, regex

I am trying to create a template from sql query by using C# and regex but I couldn't be successful. How can I do that?

For example:

My sql select query:

```py
select c.[Id], C.Name from Customer c.Surname='Smith' and c.Address like 'Newyork'
```

it must be :

```py
select c.[Id], C.Name from Customer c.Surname='{Surname}' and c.Address like '{Address}'
```

Another Sample:

```py
select c.[Id], C.Name from Customer c.Surname='Smith' and c.Address = 'xyx glk'
```

it must be :

```py
select c.[Id], C.Name from Customer c.Surname='{Surname}' and c.Address = '{Address}'
```

Another one:

```py
UPDATE table_name
SET column1 = 'value1', column2 = 'value2'
WHERE condition;
```

it must be:

```py
UPDATE table_name
SET column1 = '{column1}', column2 = '{column2}'
WHERE condition;
```

I need your help to make it. How can I use regex with C# ?

Comment: Why regex? Are you starting with some saved SQL queries and trying to generate calling code in C#?

Comment: Need a better definition of what you are trying to do, using regex with C# is simple and you can find many online tutorials, but I feel like that isnt the solution. Can you explain a bit more

Comment: If you have a bunch of queries, where you adding values to object properties like c.Surname, you dont need to use regex, you can just replace the value in `c.Surname` with what you want using a method that does object mapping

Comment: This is wrong. You must pass these data via PARAMETERS

Comment: Why aren't you using SQL parameters?  Why are you wanting to use regex?

Comment: Pengunen,  this is a little ad hominem, but as someone who has asked **371 questions** here, you certainly should have built up a sense of producing a [MCVE] and showing your efforts in the question before asking other people to just build the full solution for you.

Comment: Watch out: xkcd drop bobby tables or https://xkcd.com/1409/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you get some idea from this.
It's working.

```
 string strtext = @"select c.[Id], C.Name from Customer c.Surname='Smith' and c.Address = 'xyx glk'";
Regex rex= new Regex(@"([^\s.]+)\s*=\s*'(.*?)'");
var replaced = rex.Replace(strtext, "$1={$1}");
```

Demo :  https://regex101.com/r/aUhESX/3